# I'm using ninject 3.0 and asp.net mvc 3. I get the error rror activating IProductRepository

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I am new to MVC so im fallowing a book example. But when I run the program it gives me the error: Error activating IProductRepository
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path...

I have read a bunch of articles and other error like this one but none of them helped. 
Why is this happening if everything is the same as in the book example? Please some help would be really appreciated.

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext,
       Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null
            ? null
            : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>(); 
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
    }
```

IProductRepository.cs

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
}
```

EFProductRepository.cs

```
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
   private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
   public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get { return context.Products; }           
    }
}

public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }    
}
```

ProductController.cs

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository repoParam)
    {
        repository = repoParam;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }
}
```

Comment: call `AddBindings()` in the `NinjectControllerFactory` constructor

Comment: That was the problem @MikeDebela. Thank you so much for the fast answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to accept the `IKernel` parameter:

```
private void AddBindings(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>(); 
}
```

Then as Mike suggests call it from your `NinjectControllerFactory` constructor method:

```
public NinjectControllerFactory()
{
    ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
    AddBindings(ninjectKernal);
}
```